# MVC @Html.DropDownListFor code does not have Session instanciated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following helper in my .cshtml file:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SkillId, new SelectList(new HCMApplication.Controllers.Classes.SSCDictionaryContainer().GetDictionary("Skills"), "Key", "Value"))
```

The class SSCDictionaryContainer has the access to the ASP.NET Session and the method implementation is as following

```
public List<DictionaryItem> GetDictionary(string dictionaryName)
    {
        List<DictionaryItem> result = new List<DictionaryItem>();
        object o = Session["SSCDictionaries"];
        return result;
    }
```

Session is NULL there (to say nothing about the "o" variable). It looks like the code is running in the separate thread, that's the only case I know for session to disappear.

How to get my Session? Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you set something to session with this particular key and that session is still alive ?

Comment: Calling functions from a view is bad juju in MVC and violates separation of concerns; you should be populating a view model with a list of skills.

Comment: Your new controller instance doesn't have any state.  You can't do that.

Comment: why not to populate the dropdown list from Viewbag or ViewData. or populating with JSON and JQuery.